# Where is the Network Preview Tab in Firefox

Tags: json, api, web-scraping, firefox-developer-tools

Does Firefox Developer have a `Preview` response tab under `Network` monitoring like Chrome?

(screenshot below):

[image]

Here is a screenshot of Firefox Developer, I don't see the equivalent tab. I read through the [Firefox documentation](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/network_monitor/toolbar/index.html) on Network monitor toolbar, and I didn't see what I was looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

The reason is because I am learning about web scraping `api's`, and I want to `preview` the response in the json file similar to that in Chrome Developer (screenshot 1).

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The *Response* tab is the place to look for the preview.

Here an example of a formatted JSON response:

[image: Response tab of the Firefox DevTools Network Monitor]

By default it shows you a preview of the response if there is a formatted preview available for the content. If you want to see the raw response, you can do so by toggling the *Raw* option at the top of the tab.

For any response the DevTools don't provide a preview for you'll just see the raw response right away and there isn't a *Raw* toggle. The same may happen if the response can't be interpreted correctly due to an incorrect `Content-Type` header returned by the server.